# $\mathscr{M}$ is a $\sigma$- algebra if, and only if, it is stable under the formation of complements.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathscr{M} \subset \mathscr{P}(X)$ be a monotone class, i.e. a family which contains $X$ and is stable under countable unions of increasing sets and countable intersections of decreasing sets. Then

$\mathscr{M}$ is a $\sigma$- algebra if, and only if, it is stable under the formation of complements.

The only if direction is trivial.

However, I can't show the if direction. We need to show that a monotone class stable under complements is also closed under countable unions. So it suffices to show it for finite unions, but I can't figure this out. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: For $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $\mathcal{M}=\{X,\emptyset,\{a\},\{a,b\},\{c,d\},\{b,c,d\}\}$, we have $\mathcal{M}$ is a class monotone stable under complement and contains $X$, but it's not a $\sigma$-algebra because $\{a\}\cup\{c,d\}\notin\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: Perhaps, under "complements" one has to understand "relative complements", that is, set differences.